# Squid Proxy always 403

Tags: proxy, squid, access-control-list

I have been trying to setup Squid proxy for a good 2 hours now, I dont want any authorizations or any blacklists. I just want all requests to get accepted. I have already tried `http_access allow all`, `acl all src all` and a lot of other methods (pretty much every method you can find on the first 3 google result pages) already, but I always get a 403 code when I actually try to make a request through it.

Comment: You should consider adding additional information about the entries in the relevant log files etc.

Answer (score 0):

Code 403 usually means something got blocked at your proxy, most probably due ACL configuration. You can debug this by changing the logging to

```
debug_options ALL,0 85,2 88,2
```

- this way you will get verbose explanation why something was allowed/denied in your `cache.log` logfile.